# Apache Ignite: How to Use Windows Certificate Store for SSL/TLS Authentication for Server Node

Tags: ignite

I'm using Ignite 2.16.0 and trying to use the Windows Certificate Store for SSL/TLS authentication instead of a java keystore file. The [documentation](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/security/ssl-tls) is clear for how to use a .pfx file for the IgniteClientConfiguration. However, the server node uses an IgniteConfiguration which expects an SslContextFactory which has properties for a keystore file path and password. How do I configure this when I don't want to use a java keystore file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further research and looking at the Ignite code I found that it's possible to set the KeyStoreType to PKCS12 and then reference the pfx file directly in the IgniteConfiguration in the SslContextFactory object:

```
            SslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory
            {
                KeyStoreFilePath = "C:\\Temp\\MyCertificateFile.pfx",
                KeyStorePassword = "MyPasswordHere",
                KeyStoreType = "PKCS12"
            }
```

When I start the Ignite server I get the expected message in the log that tls/ssl is on:

Security status [authentication=off, sandbox=off, tls/ssl=off]

Answer (score 1):

JKS is the default way how certificates are stored by JDK. I am not sure does Apache Ignite support any other keystores types for java, but I can see the following method:

https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/ssl/SslContextFactory.html#setKeyStoreType-java.lang.String-

Default one is JKS. But looks like it may be extended for other types (maybe it is). You can contact dev@ignite.apache.org and ask about PFX storage support:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ignite/site/ignite-6036/community/resources.html

Just in case, you can convert your PFX to JKS:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore cert.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 
-destkeystore cert.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right path. I found that I could convert my pfx to a jks and it does work. However, I also found that there is a setting to use the pfx directly in the configuration. I will add an answer with the details.